# THREE.EffectComposer.scene.addObject( THREE.EffectComposer.quad ); has no method 'addObject'

Tags: three.js

First, before I ask you some newbie questions, I would like thanks MrDoob & co for all this good work, I'm really pleased to use three.js.

But actually, I'm trying to use some shaders and post effects to render a beautiful sun in my solar system. For that I inspired myself a lot from your lava taurus example.

When I adapt it in my code, I got the following JS error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addObject' EffectComposer.js:129
THREE.WebGLRenderer 49 Three.js:331
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function BloomPass.js:27
```

The first seems to be an classic js error but I cannot find the reason, the code seems good :

```
THREE.EffectComposer.scene = new THREE.Scene();
THREE.EffectComposer.scene.addObject( THREE.EffectComposer.quad );
```

And the second points to :

```
this.materialScreen = new THREE.MeshShaderMaterial( {
```

Finally, I tried with your sample code without modifying it (I just deleted the stats part in the code) and didn't include these two files (cause I didn't find the source) :

```
<script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="js/Stats.js"></script>
```

And I get the same first error related to the effectComposer.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. First I hadn't the right include files (mine were older). Then; I didn't structure my code well and missed couple of things.

Now it is fixed, and I don't know actually who did the lava taurus in your examples Mr.Doob but the shaders are simply stunning.

If you wanna take a look to my solarsystem : http://www.scgaming.eu/

I work it out, but I'm thinking about how optimise it and how writing the code better than it h